# How to generate and sample from a random distribution fit to observed values in R?

Tags: r

I have been using an existing function `random_steps` from the package `amt`. I need to produce a gamma distribution of values fit to observed values from my data, then sample from those to give me possible alternatives to what was observed. The trouble is that the observed values range from 0 to 53, but the generated ones from 0 to 522. Obviously the function is giving me values that are not only implausible but impossible.

I do not want to go through the source code (https://github.com/jmsigner/amt/blob/master/R/random_steps.R) looking for something to fix, so I am hoping that someone can give me an escape so that I can leave `amt` behind. However, I have not been able to find a solution elsewhere. Surely there is a simple way to use existing values to generate a distribution and then to sample from that?

These are the density plots of the values observed in the data (left) and generated by `random_steps` (right).
[image]

My data set has over 2 million rows, which is presenting a problem for me in demonstrating exactly what is happening. Essentially the code reads:

```
stepTime <- 60
toleranceTime <- 15

tracks <- lapply(split(df, df$name), function(x){

# make animal tracks and resample to consistent times
  trk <- mk_track(df, .x=long, .y=lat, .t=timestamp, id = name) %>%
    track_resample(rate = minutes(stepTime),tolerance = minutes(toleranceTime))
  
  # burst steps
  burst <- steps_by_burst(trk, keep_cols = "start")
  
  # create random steps using fitted gamma and von mises distributions and append
  rnd_stps <- burst %>%  random_steps(n_control = stepNumber)
  
}) %>% reduce(rbind)
```

And it produces alternative values 4.03% of which are greater than the highest observed value.

When I generate an entirely new distribution as suggested below, I get a very nice curve that lies entirely within the bounds of possible values.
[image: fitted gamma distribution]
However, when I then draw values from that to create my sample of possible values for comparison to the observed ones, the density at the lower end is so high that all the sampled values fall below 1. My observed values then range from 0 to 53 while my alternatives range from 0 to 1.

Any hints on how to get a distribution that reflects reality more closely?

Thanks so much!

Comment: how frequent are values above 53 when you sample? Can you post a reproducible example with density plot of observed values and sampled values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familar with `random_steps` but fitting a gamma distribution to a set of observed values is not that difficult.  Here's one way of doing it.

If a gamma distribution is parameterised in terms of scale and shape parameters, then the mean is given by shape * scale and the variance by shape * scale * scale.  So calculate the mean and variance of your sample and derive scale as variance / mean and hence shape = mean / scale.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) for details.

Here's a worked example.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Generate some gamma data
set.seed(123)
d <- tibble(x = rgamma(1000, shape=3, scale=1.5)) 

# Calculate summary statistics
stats <- d %>% summarise(Mean=mean(x), Variance=var(x))
stats
# A tibble: 1 x 2
   Mean Variance
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1  4.32     5.65

# Derive parameter estimates
scale <- stats$Variance / stats$Mean
shape <-  stats$Mean / scale

> scale
[1] 1.307148
> shape
[1] 3.305911

# Derive fitted PDF and compare with empirical PDF
fitted <- tibble(x=seq(0,15,0.25), y=dgamma(x, shape=shape, scale=scale))
d %>% ggplot + geom_histogram(aes(x=x, y=..density..), bins=20) + geom_line(data=fitted, aes(x=x, y=y), colour="blue")
```

If you still have a significant disparity between your observed data and the fitted distribution, that would suggest that your observations do not follow a gamma distribution.

[image]

Comment: FWIW this is called the "method of moments"

Comment: Indeed it is, Ben.